# iPhone Development

Tags: iphone

Thanks in Advance: m new in iPhone development. I have used code given at the following URL.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240111/changing-an-image-via-dragging-swiping-with-finger-in-order-to-make-a-3d-model

But m getting error in the below given piece of code.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.SFImage];
}
```

Error message is: "Property 'SFImage' not found" and "Request for member 'SFImage' is something not a structure or union"

Kindly help me out how to fix these errors. I m wondering may be i have missed something, but don't know what.

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

This code assumes that there is a property on your class called `SFImage`, and the compiler is telling you there isn’t one. From the code it appears that it’s supposed to be an image view, so if you replace that with a reference to whatever you named the view containing the image you should be good.

By the way, in general, try to understand the code you are writing. It makes you a better programmer and will prevent many headaches in the future.

Comment: Thanx i have fixed it. Its about week that i have started iPhone development. kindly help me to fix one more thing i.e. "if (deltaX >= kMinimumGestureLength && currentPosition.x < gestureStartPoints .x ) " what would be "kMinimumGestureLength"

Comment: Please explain how you fixed it for anyone who might come across this through Google and such :)

Comment: in the same way u told me:)
i have replaced "SFImage" with my "ImageView" name

Comment: m waiting for ur help, for 2nd question i have asked

Comment: You should really be doing some more upfront reading and writing code yourself. The convention is that variable names starting with `k` are constants, e.g. `static const kSomething = 12;`.

Comment: Thanx m done with all errors..,
now i have to fix one thing that is, i need to override this function "- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event"
any help would be appreciated.,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in following statement

```
gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.SFImage];
```

Compiler cannot find SFImage (self.SFImage) as a property within class, the reason may be developer is using the class name rather than using object reference, and this is just an assumption by understanding  the limited snippet of your code available here.